# Turn old Android device or phone into homemade Chromecast

Tags: android, google-cast

I have been reviewing the [Beaglebone Black](http://beagleboard.org/BLACK) and would like to know if I install Android on the device how do I enable casting/mirroring?  The Beaglebone Black has a Network card and wifi can be added.  Is it possible to create an open source Chromecast device with greater capabilities?

This is very a promising board, I'd love to build my own device similar to [Samsungs Galaxy HomeSync](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/cell-phones-accessories/GT-B9150ZKYXAR).

Comment: What is your definition of "an open source Chromecast device"? The software on the Chromecast itself is not open source on the whole, though pieces might be.

Comment: @CommonsWare <br/><br/> In production and development, open source as a development model promotes a universal access via a free license to a product's design or blueprint, and universal redistribution of that design or blueprint, including subsequent improvements to it by anyone.  [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source).    <br/> <br/>  I would like to build a device that uses the same protocols and or technology that Google uses with hardware such as the Beaglebone Black that supports Android?

Comment: I have been working with open source for ~15 years; I know what it is. However, the software on the Chromecast itself is not open source in general, nor are their protocols open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. Each Chromecast has a device-specific certificate which is used to authenticate to an official SDK that it is a "real" Chromecast. Withtout this certificate, your Fake-Chromecast would not work with anything which expects that certificate.

For more info: https://github.com/thibauts/node-castv2/issues/2#issuecomment-69466112

Comment: What about getting the device certified by google?  Would it be possible then?  And how might one go about getting a device certified?

Comment: It's _possible_ but probably only if you are a big company that makes and sells millions of devices annually.

Comment: I noticed the other day as i was researching Google launched the Nexus Player which will do exactly what I want to do. It looks like it may even support an external hard drive.

If only it were possible for us who want to use open hardware.

@justhecuke i search online for ways to get a certificate for hardware.   Anyone know where to go?

Comment: The only way to get a certificate is to ask Google for one. They seem to be holding tightly onto certificates, so I wouldn't get my hopes up if I were you.